# csv file is empty after uploading to the blobstorage

Tags: c#

Im using .Net Core c# in trying to create a CSV file and upload it to the blobstorage.  I'm not sure why the file ends up empty:

```
public async Task<UploadToCloudResponse> ExecuteUseCaseAsync(RequestRefundModel file)
{
    UploadToCloudResponse uploadResponse = new();
    var container = new BlobServiceClient(this.connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = container.GetBlobContainerClient("payoutrequests");
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName.ExecuteUseCase(PrefixFileNames.Refund));            
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
          
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(file.FileBody);
             memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            var url = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            uploadResponse.Success = true;
            uploadResponse.URL = url;
            return uploadResponse;
        } 
      
    }
```

The input file is a class containing a list of another class named FileBody.  It does contain data (I have tested it), but I'm not sure why it's not writing the data to the file.

Comment: Just like a VHS tape (remember those?) you need to **rewind** the `MemoryStream` after you write to it so that the Azure upload code can read what you've written from the beginning. Do this by setting `memoryStream.Position = 0` after your `WriteRecords` call.

Comment: When you call `UploadAsync()` the `Position` of `memoryStream` will be _after_ the data you just wrote to it.  Try `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` or `memoryStream.Position = 0;` before uploading.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthewsedited my question and added what you said,still the file is empty

Comment: @Daiupdated my question,could you take a look?still im getting a file with 0 size

Comment: @Dai had to add the Fluch after i write,its working now,thanks a lot

Comment: Alternatively, you can adjust the scope of your inner `using` blocks to just contain `WriteRecords()` so those resources can get cleaned up earlier and you'll no longer need to explicitly call `Flush()`: `using (var streamWriter = ...) using (var csvWriter = ...) { csvWriter.WriteRecords(file.FileBody); } memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);`